# UserControl Raise Events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I add an onfocus event to a web user control (.ascx) expection it to raise event when it gets focus but it doesn't. Is it not intended to work this way and how can I get it to raise the event? Here is sample below, but it doesn't work.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.vb" 
Inherits="RaiseEventUserControl.WebUserControl1" %> 
<div style="padding: 5px; background-color: #C0C0C0"> 
TB1: 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
TB2: 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<%@ Register Src="WebUserControl1.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl1" TagPrefix="uc1" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
<title></title>    
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function RaiseEvent(obj) {  
        alert("Event was raised for: " + obj.id)  
    }  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
<div>  
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" onfocus="RaiseEvent(this)" />  
    <br />  
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl12" runat="server" onfocus="RaiseEvent(this)" />  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: What does your WebUserControl look like? Does it have any elements that can trigget focus event?

Comment: onfocus is not actually an asp.net tag. That would probably just render an "onfocus" attribute on a surrounding div, but onfocus is meaningless for a div.

Comment: The WebUserControl is posted at the top of the code block. it is just a sample but it has 2 textbox's

Comment: what id like to do is when the user control recieves focus, fire off some server side code through __doPostBack in Javascript.

Comment: There's no general concept of a "usercontrol receiving focus." Only input controls can receive focus. So you could add onfocus to all the input controls in your usercontrol, or do something more elegant like having jquery do that for you. This all sounds a bit sketchy, though, what exactly do you want to happen on the server, and why can't it be done when the form is loaded?

Comment: Well...I am converting a Windows App to Web App. The server side is actually pulling scripts from sql server and compiling through code dom and returning the results based on the events fired off on client side. I have this all working except for when user "Enters" or puts "Focus" into a UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/). In your head element, add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name^="WebUserControl"]').focusin(function () {
        $(this).val("i have focus");
    });
});
</script>
```

What this does is, grabs the input elements whose name starts with "WebUserControl" and adds a "got focus" event. The handler for that event places "i have focus" as the value for that input element.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that worked for textbox. How about DropDownList and CheckBox? And do you know how I could fire off a __doPostBack within you function? Basically after the event is fired off once it doesn't need to be fired again unless the user leaves the user control and re-enters into it.

Comment: You need to modify the selector to change from "input" to something else, for other element types. Also, on help on how to post back to the server you can check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks again. I will have to look into the jquery methods. That might be a little more efficient then what i am currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

The way that this would be rendered to the page is that a "onFocus" attribute would be added to the div that represents the control.  This is not something that supports focus.  You might add the "onFocus" item to say your first text field in the control or something similar to be able to raise the event if needed.